# Nginx Server Block for SSL don't work

Tags: nginx, ssl

My site is available without ssl via http but not via https. With https://www.example.com occurs a network timeout. Also the nginx error.log shows no errors. Why am I not able to redirect and reach the site via https?

This is my nginx server block file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com example.org www.example.org
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;  

    root /var/www/example;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri  =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Output of netstat -tulpen|grep 443

```
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          417562386   339/nginx: worker p
    tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          417562387   339/nginx: worker p
```

Edit:
This is my nginx.conf

```
user xy;
worker_processes 5;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 4096;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I found it. It was simply a fault in the firewall. Port 443 wasn't allowed.
But it still doesn't redirect from http:// to https://

Answer (score 0):

With that config there is no way for your site to be accessible via HTTP.
If it still is, then config is not used.

First of all, try to stop nginx and then start it again. Sometimes it hangs and does not restart correctly.

Then check, does your site really work from that part of configuration.
Add access_log directive to log requescts into some unusial (for your configuration) file. Something like /tmp/nginx.test.log (just to avoid write permissions handling).

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log

If you are accessing your site and no line are adding to log, then it is just served by other part of config.
**Don't forget to remove that logging and log itself after the check!**

Comment: Well I did like you told me. First stop and start nginx but nothing changed. Afterwards I wrote access_log /home/userx/test.nginx.log in front of the first server block.
Reloaded nginx and same result as before and I have something inside the test.nginx.log `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [19/Oct/2016:20:18:40 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"`
Ok I tried to put it into the fist server block but the same result as before.
So I wrote it instead of that into the 2nd server block with the ssl config and now I got now new lines